# Get product name and sku in grid using join

Tags: join-table

Here is my code

```
$vendorTableName = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('marketplace/vendor');
    $vendorproductsTableName = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('marketplace/vendorpro');
    $productsTableName = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('catalog/product');
    $collection = Mage::getModel("marketplace/vendorpro")->getCollection();

    $collection->getSelect()
    ->joinLeft(array('ce1' => $vendorTableName), 'ce1.vendor_id=main_table.vendor_id', array('vendor_name','vendor_contact_email'));

    $collection->getSelect()
    ->joinLeft(
        array('prod' => 'catalog_product_entity'), 
        'prod.entity_id = main_table.mageproduct_id',
        array('sku')
    )
    ->joinLeft(
        array('cpev' => 'catalog_product_entity_varchar'), 
        'cpev.entity_id=main_table.mageproduct_id', 
        array('name' => 'value')
    );
```

I am not getting correct data i have only two entry in database but it returns more than 2 where is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$vendorTableName = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('marketplace/vendor');
    $vendorproductsTableName = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('marketplace/vendorpro');
    $productsTableName = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('catalog/product');
    $collection = Mage::getModel("marketplace/vendorpro")->getCollection();
$collection->getSelect()
        ->joinLeft(array('ce1' => $vendorTableName), 'ce1.vendor_id=main_table.vendor_id', array('vendor_name','vendor_contact_email'));
        $entityTypeId = Mage::getModel('eav/entity')
                ->setType('catalog_product')
                ->getTypeId();
        $prodNameAttrId = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')
            ->loadByCode($entityTypeId, 'name')
            ->getAttributeId();
        $collection->getSelect()
        ->joinLeft(
            array('prod' => 'catalog_product_entity'), 
            'prod.entity_id = main_table.mageproduct_id',
            array('sku')
        )
        ->joinLeft(
            array('cpev' => 'catalog_product_entity_varchar'), 
            'cpev.entity_id=prod.entity_id AND cpev.attribute_id='.$prodNameAttrId.'', 
            array('name' => 'value')
        );
```

Using this u can get proper sku and name of product.

It works for me.